# How can I make port forwarding using tor?

Tags: nat, tor

I need to open ports for such services. But the problem is that I have problems with the NAT so I was thinking using tor to make port forwarding but at the moment I dont have any idea or way to do it.

I researched a little and there's some ways starting a tor service and using no-ip but not sure if will work.

It's possible or which recommend me to port forward without NAT?

Comment: Even if you use TOR, that doesn’t chnage the fact, you still have to forward ports to direct traffic on a given port to your machine. TOR won’t solve your problem

Answer (score 6):

You don't need any open incoming ports to run a Tor hidden service, or even really worry about NAT.  You certainly don't need a dynamic DNS provider.

Your Tor peer simply must be able to connect to some of the Tor relays and you will need some time for your `.onion` address to propogate through the distributed hash table.

Exact process is [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/672/how-do-onion-addresses-exactly-work).

The Tor peer builds circuits to the so-called "rendezvous" point - so it has initiated the connection (meaning as long as you have *outgoing* access you are fine) and maintains it - and it receives data through these circuits with the rendezvous points.

Now, where ports come into play is in configuring the hidden service.

- Typically, you want program you want to make available via Tor listening on *localhost* or 127.0.0.1
- You specify in the Tor hidden service configuration in this way in the configuration file - for example:

  HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080`

  Port 80 is what the `onion` address users must use.  `127.0.0.1:8080` is what your program that you want to make available via Tor must be listening on.  Tor does the rest.

  You do not have to have port 80 open on your router for this to work, and you don't have to care about NAT.

Comment: but where i must to specify this : HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080 im little lost in which file of tor i must to specify this

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-hidden-service-tor-site-set-anonymous-website-server/